# Use of ViewPager2 and Navigation causing multiple instantiation of home fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-viewpager2

I am new to Android development and am completing a project in which I am required to use Jetpack Navigation.

My app is a single-activity, multiple-fragment design.

I am also trying to use ViewPager2 to swipe between my "home" Fragment A, to Fragment B (also, I am using indicator dots to show the user where they are in the ViewPager). In future I will have a Fragment C, which I would like to navigate to with conventional navigation from Navigation B.

I am really struggling to figure out how to use navigation and ViewPager2 together harmoniously: at the moment, their co-existence is causing a duplicate instantiation of Fragment A, which leads to other bugs (chiefly, I collect a Flow in Fragment A and this also gets duplicated in undesirable ways).

This how my activity_main.xml looks:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
>

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:translationZ="2dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:outlineProvider="none"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"/>

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tab_layout"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I already hate the way this is set up, as it just feels wrong that the ViewPager does not *contain* the FragmentContainerView, but I'm not sure how else to do it since ViewPager2 does not allow child views.

And then, this is how I set things up in my MainActivity.kt:

```
const val FRAGMENT_COUNT = 2

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var navController: NavController
private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager2
private lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout
private lateinit var pagerAdapter: PagerAdapter
private val viewModel: MainViewModel by inject()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout)
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
    pagerAdapter = PagerAdapter(this)
    viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.myNavHostFragment) as NavHostFragment
    navController = navHostFragment.navController

    TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) { _, _ -> }.attach()

    viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            super.onPageSelected(position)
            
            val currentDestinationId = navController.currentDestination?.id

            when (position) {
                0 -> {
                    if (currentDestinationId != R.id.newSuggestionFragment) {
                        navController.navigate(R.id.action_favouritesFragment_to_newSuggestionFragment)
                    }
                }
                1 -> {
                    if (currentDestinationId != R.id.favouritesFragment) {
                        navController.navigate(R.id.action_newSuggestionFragment_to_favouritesFragment)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })

    viewModel.message.observe(this) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, it, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

}
class PagerAdapter(fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity): FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return FRAGMENT_COUNT
    }

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment =
     when(position){
        0 -> NewSuggestionFragment()
        1 -> FavouritesFragment()
        else -> NewSuggestionFragment()
    }
}
```

I've tried researching online but I'm struggling to find clear information on this (most likely, I just don't understand the underlying issues well enough). I'd really appreciate any advice on fixing this.